# Cryptic dplyr error when trying to knit html

Tags: r, knitr, dplyr

I have a snippet that depends on a package that I wrote. I'm trying to knit a markdown document and am getting an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : not a vector
Calls: <Anonymous> ... freduce -> <Anonymous> -> bind_rows -> rbind_all -> .Call
```

The same snippet runs in the console, and the previous line is a `lapply` that returns a list of data frames. There's confidential data and it'd take a while to come up with a reproducible example so I thought I'd see if others have any tips.

Comment: `traceback()` or RStudio debugger may be helpful. As alternative take a while to come up with reproducible example (or should I say RLY!?).

Comment: `traceback()` doesn't give me anything and the debugger just gives me the error

Comment: Maybe you have a different set and order of libraries being loaded. Try them both from clean starts with all libraries explicitly loaded.

Comment: @organicagave But you know that you need to call it immediately after error? Try to inspect what you send to `bind_rows` cause seems like it's something that it can't handle.